# Related workitems on Build Summary with releases branches

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch

I've set up a build, with release/* as a trigger. My problem is that on every new release branch, summary page shows all commits on all repo history and all work items related. There is any way to only the new commits and work items since the last release branch?

If I use the same branch, merging the new changes, it works as expected, but if I create a new release branch it shows all history.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is any way to only the new commits and work items since the last release branch?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this. Because this behavior is **by designed**.

> Azure Devops determines what changesets should be mapped to a build
>   **based on the Source Repository Mappings (Build vNext) in the build definition and the last successful build**.
>
> So, you will see a list of the changesets with files committed in the
>   lowest common base of any of the mapped folders including all their
>   descendants, since the latest successful build. **Whenever you get a
>   successful build the list will shorten and only show the last
>   check-in**.

So, when we create a new release branch, there is no any latest successful build, it will include all the commits and linked work items.

Besides, there is a [rejected user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/12806013-build-summary-should-contain-only-the-change-sets) about it, you can check the feedback for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I understand this is by designed, but it makes any sense?
If you use GitFlow, you can't know what are the associated commits and workitems of a build?

Comment: @RodrigoMocca, Indeed, in this case, you can open a new user voice here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Thanks for your help.